# django: Images are not loading

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I need to show images in templates. The images are fetched from models. My `models.py` reside in an app named `services`:

```
class Car_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 25, blank=False)
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/models')
```

I have added these lines in my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')    # i added it later
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

I have also added this line in my *project_name's* `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I am trying to get the images in my templates through this code:

```
{% load static %}
  {% for c in ca %}
    <p><strong>{{ c.car_no }}</strong>--<em>{{ c.car_model }}</em>--{{ c.garage }}</p>
    <img src="{{ c.car_model.photo.url }}" height="200" />
    <form action="{%url 'booking' c.id c.garage.id %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" name="the_selected_car" value="Select this car">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

But whatever I try photos aren't showing. I tried by placing this:
`+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in my `services` app's `urls.py` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add **MEDIA_ROOT** and **MEDIA_URL** in **settings.py** and load media urls in **urls.py**

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
 ........  

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Your could Refactor your `upload_to` in photo field

**1.** If you want to upload images in `static` director

```py
photo = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/models')
```

And set static folder in MEDIA_ROOT as below

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**2.** If you want to upload images in  `media` director

Since your are storing uploaded images I would suggest store in defferent director like media , uploads 
Change your field as below.

```py
photo = models.ImageField (upload_to ='media/images/car_model')
```

Now All your images related to Car_Model will be saved inside media/images/car_model
And set media folder in MEDIA_ROOT as below MEDIA_ROOT as below

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: The second approach is better.

Comment: Is the `{% load static %}` template tag used to load CSS, JS only, but not media files?

Comment: I did as you suggested, updated the path to `'media/images/models'`, moved the files to the `media` folder from `static` folder. Defined                                         `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` in `settings.py`. Added `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` and 
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in urls.py. But still when opening the page i am geting this error **"GET /media/static/images/models/nissan-frontier-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1873**
.

Comment: But when i'm hard coding the url like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/profile-photos/SoloCharacter.jpg`, it's showing!

Comment: from where the `/static/` is coming in the path `"GET /media/static/images/models/nissan-frontier-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1873`,  I think the problem lies there!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't include `MEDIA` Urls in your urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```